# What is the relationship between $p$-norm and 2-norm for any $p$-norm?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, optimization, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

I know that there are some general inequalities between the $2$-norm and $1$-norm or $\infty$-norm

Suppose I am given an arbitrary $p$-norm, obviously $p \geq 1$

What can we say about the inequality between $\|x\|_2$ and $\|x\|_p$?

Comment: $||x||_p\le ||x||_r$ when $r<p$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Does there exist a general result that says $\|x\|_p \leq \alpha(p, r) \|x\|_r$, when $r > p$, for $\alpha(p, r)$ some function that depends on $p, r$. I remember there was something like $\|x\|_1 \leq \sqrt{n}\|x\|_2$

Comment: $||x||_r<n^{1/r-1/p}||x||_p$, when $r<p$, in $n$ dimensions; cf. [this reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Relations_between_p-norms)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thank you. Do you have a reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on the underlying measure space. The inequality $\|x\|_p\leq\|x\|_r$ does not always hold for $p>r$. For instance,  if $X=(0,1)$ with the Lebesgue measure,
then it is not true that $\|f\|_2\leq \|f\|_1$. For example, the function $x^{-1/2}$ belongs to $L_1(0,1)$ but not to $L_2(0,1)$. In fact, if $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ is a probability space, i.e., $\mu(X)=1$, then then
$\|f\|_r\leq \|f\|_p$ if $r<p$, which is the reverse inequality of that suggested in the first comment above.

Comment: What about finite-dimensional spaces?